What's the latin verb for "to fetch"?
I'm looking for the  meaning of "to go and get"I saw the verb "peto" but I didn't understand when I read on L&S.
How did a roman say to someone fetch something?

How about "arcesso, arcessivi" [3] = send for, call; procure; summons, accuse; fetch (Oxford).

"obstetricem arcesse" = "(Go and) fetch the midwife!" (Ter. Eun. 3.2.56),

which uses the imperative form of the verb.
Thanks to Joonas & cmw for pointing out that "arcesso" may mean "to fetch" only in the sense of people, not necessarily things.
EDIT 18/11/2024:
For a verb that will cover both uses I thought of "adduco": in Lewis & Short there is some confusion: "...to lead or bring a person or THING(?) to a place, to take or conduct from one place or another (of living things which have the power of motion, while "affero" is properly used of things).
L&S stated "things", second line--confusion?
Turning to "affero"--it has many definitions based on fetch, carry, bring (L&S; Wiki; Oxford) e.g.

"adferte nobis de fructibus terrae," (Vulg. Num. 13.21) =


"Bring us some of the fruits of the earth!"


"adferte litteras ad aliquem," (Cic. Att. 8.6) =


"Bring letters to someone!"

Where "adferte" is the plural imperative of the verb.
(L&S say that "adfero" is a better form than "affero", for the one verb.)

Can the object of this verb be an object or does it have to be a person? I can't tell based on what you quote.

@Joonas llmavirta: The object is the midwife;  if the Latin is wrong, it's Terence's mistake and not mine--what a blessed relief!

You miss the point. The object of that example is indeed a person, and I'm not questioning its validity. My question was whether that same verb can also have a non-person object. Can a dog fetch a ball with that verb, based on the dictionaries? This is not a rhetorical question; it'd be good if you could edit in some details to answer this if the dictionaries have any.

Yeah, looking at Lewis and Short, it's "fetch a person", as in "go and call them forth." That's why it also works with ideas. But I don't think it has, at least just by looking at L&S, the idea of picking up an object and carrying it back. But it definitely works for people.

Tony, one option is to add a note like "This verb only seems applicable when the object is a human. For other uses of 'fetch' you need a different verb." at the end of your answer. Specifying constraints like this makes answers much more valuable. My previous comments were all about asking whether there is such a constraint.
